# Touchscreen of official 7" LCD does not work when powered with POE HAT+ 4 A output

Tags: pi-4, poe

Facing a strange issue, the official 7" LCD - only touchscreen (display is ok) does not work when I power the RPi 4 B with official POE HAT (4A). When I remove the POE HAT and power with USB-C connector then display and touchscreen works fine. I am using latest Raspberry Pi OS with desktop 32 bit (Debian Bullseye).

I understand that the FAN on POE HAT+ is controlled by I2C and touch information of the LCD also uses I2C, could there be a address setting or similar settings causing my touchscreen (Display works fine) not to work when POE HAT+ is connected.

How to check the addressing for these two devices? I can let the FAN run continuously if that can help to get the touchscreen working.

Whenever I power Raspberry Pi with POE HAT  the mouse pointer automatically comes up, which I guess means touchscreen is disabled.

Please guide